# best practice database design

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

My tables and design descriptions are:

- **Device** table: 
  (*id*, *specification*)
- **Android OS** table:
  (*id*, *instance_id*, *timestamp*)
- **IOS** table:
  (*id*, *token*, *merge_id*, *break_point*)
- Any device will have only *one* **os** (android/ios).
  Check that android and ios table column are different.

What can be the best database relation design?

Answer (score 0):

check the `EER` (Extended Entity Relation) diagram below:
[image]

Your tables will be something like this:

1. **Operating_Systems**(*id*)
2. **IOS**(*OS_id*, *token*, *merge_id*, *break_point*) -> *OS_id* references to
   **Operating_Systems**(*id*)
3. **Android**(*OS_id*, *instance_id*, *timestamp*) -> *OS_id* references to
   **Operating_Systems**(*id*)
4. **Device**(*id*, *specification*, *OS_id*) -> *OS_id* references to
   **Operating_Systems**(*id*)

I've to say that there are different ways to implement inheritance in `EER` diagram ... so I choose only one of them.And also put underline for each `ID` attribute in `EER` diagram.